# Why is Google cloud platform with uWebSockets.js giving me error code 502

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket

I've coded a server in Node.js using uWebSockets.js and deployed it to Google Cloud App Engine.

The server itself works fine when I run it on the local network but when I try to connect it through the gcloud URL it throws the error (to the client):

```
received bad response code from server 502
```

Could it be something to do with the URL itself? The `gcloud deploy app` command gives me a `https://` url by default, so I’m using `var ws = new WebSocket('https://[PROJECT_ID].ts.r.appspot.com');` in my client-side because I assume that the URL will act as a proxy for my WebSocket, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it...

Any help/advice appreciated

Comment: App Engine standard doesn't (!?) support WebSockets. You can use flexible (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-websockets-support-for-app-engine-flexible-environment) or Cloud Run (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DazWilkin mentioned, WebSockets can be used with [App Engine Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity) and with [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets).

App Engine standard environment doesn't support this.